# how to network computers to access locally served content via web browser without internet connection

Tags: networking, router, lan, wired-networking, mamp

I'm hoping to get a broad overview to the best approach for this - I've built a web application that does not require the internet for any external resources - all content is served locally, and I've set it up on a mac running apache, mysql, php, and node.

I need two windows 10 surface tablets to be able to access the web address of that the mac mini is serving. They can be hard wired (via USB ethernet cable?) to the server computer, but they should only use a local network - not the internet.

My basic assumption is that I will need to get a router, and connect all the computers to this router via ethernet cable, and then somehow I'm assuming the tablets will be able to see the ip address of the server - but I'm not clear on the specifics, or the steps to take to set this all up. It's been a bit hard to research so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server needs to be on the same local network that the clients are accessing.

Devices are on the same network when (the following is simplified):

- A.  They are all on the same switch or bridge (layer 1/2)

  - A switch is a device with a bunch of Ethernet ports.  Computers connected to it can talk to each other after setting up IP addresses or having DHCP from a DHCP server do that.
  - Typical residential and SOHO routers have a built-in switch.  All the LAN ports are actually a switch.  Any system plugged into a LAN port can physically talk to one on another LAN port.
  - Typical residential and SOHO routers that feature wireless automatically bridge it to the LAN ports.  So effectively anything on that router's Wifi will be on the same "switch" as the LAN.
  - Advanced routers may let you create additional AP "guest networks" that won't be able to see the LAN - this lets guest access not interfere with your LAN access.
- B. They are all using the right set of IP addresses (layer 3)

  - Systems on a common network that are expected to talk to each other need to have the same subnet mask, and an IP that falls within the range that the subnet mask describes.
  - Typical residential and SOHO routers have a built-in DHCP server that normally assigns this automatically.

but:

- A server needs a fixed IP so you can know it's IP beforehand.  Most decent routers will let you create something called a *reservation*.  This tells the router to give a computer with a specific MAC address the same IP, every time.

So, you need to:

- Connect your server to whatever router your tablets are using for Wifi.
- If you don't have a wireless router in this location, and your tablets are using cellular connections, then you'll need to get landline Internet access and set up a wireless router, or look into making your web app available over the Internet.

  - Internet access to this router is needed for tablets to be able to access Internet while on Wifi.
  - It's probably possible to set up tablets to access Internet over cellular while accessing certain local networks over Wifi but it will require a lot of manual tweaking that you'd have to do for each machine that wants to access (assuming it is possible).
  - Windows automatic network setup will generally want the Internet accessible if it tries to connect to an access point.
- Find out the MAC address of your Mac Mini.
- Login to the router's configuration page and configure a reservation for your server and pick an IP for it (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX).  Make sure this IP is not in the range of IPs that DHCP hands out.
- Tell people who want to go to your web app to enter `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` in their address bar, or make a shortcut for them.

Comment: Thanks - this is really useful. The only question I still have is, when I suggested to an IT person that things be connected via wifi, he told me "that is a terrible idea". Do I need wifi? Is it enough to have a router and no modem, and just have everything connected via ethernet? I don't need the greater internet, just the content served up from the local server. Also, do you have a recommended router? I don't need a ton of security, as this will be used for testing, not production.

Comment: Wifi is slower and less stable than wired.  You should avoid connecting the Mac Mini to anything via wireless, but in a pinch it will work, just more slowly.  If you don't need the greater Internet at all, just get a 4-port wireless router from a department store and use/set that up.  Then connect the Mac Mini to the router, and the tablets to the router's Wifi SSID.  Tablets will not get Internet but can still reach the Mac Mini for testing.  You'll need to set up DHCP as talked about above.